# Calculate the time complexity of recurrence relation f(n) = f(n/2) + f(n/3)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, recurrence

How to calculate time complexity of recurrence relation f(n) = f(n/2) + f(n/3). We have base case at n=1 and n=0.

How to calculate time complexity for general case i.e f(n) = f(n/x) + f(n/y), where x<n and y<n.

Edit-1 :(after first answer posted) every number considered is integer.

Edit-2 :(after first answer posted) I like the answer given by Mbo but is it possible to answer this without using any fancy theorem like master theorem etc.Like by making tree etc.

However users are free to answer the way they like and i will try to understand.

Comment: First, this looks wrong if n can be a float. so let's assume n is an integer. Also you might want to explain what are the x and y (maybe they are defined as constants in your program. Then, you can take n = 10 and see how it goes until you reach the end of the program. that will give you an idea of the time complexity. Basically here, it looks like a fibonnaci-style algorithm to me. If you don't cache the processed values, it's basically creating 1 loop (recusive call) for each function call. So my guess would be something like O(2n)

Comment: I added example with tree building

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In "layman terms" you can get dependence with larger coefficient:

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + O(1)
```

build call tree for `n=2^k` and see that the last tree level contains `2^k` items, higher level `2^k-1` items, next one `2^k-2` and so on. Sum of sequence (geometric progression)

```
2^k + 2^k-1 + 2^k-2 + ... + 1 = 2^(k+1) = 2*n
```

so complexity for this dependence is linear too.

Now get dependence with smaller (zero) second coefficient:

```
 T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)
```

and ensure in linear complexity too.

Seems clear that complexity of recurrence in question lies between complexities for these simpler examples, and is linear.

---

In general case recurrences with complex branching might be solved with [Aktra-Bazzi method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method) (more general approach than [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)))

I assume that dependence is

```
T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/3) + O(1)
```

In this case `g=1`, to find `p` we should numerically solve

```
(1/2)^p + (1/3)^p = 1
```

and get `p~0.79`, then integrate

```
T(x) = Theta(x^0.79 * (1 + Int[1..x]((1/u^0.79)*du))) = 
       Theta(x^0.79 * (1 + 4.8*x^0.21 - 4.8) =  
       Theta(x^0.79 + 4.8*x) =  
       Theta(x)
```

So complexity is linear